# error: invalid user-defined conversion from ‘char’ to ‘std::vector<std::basic_string<char>

Tags: c++, string, c++11, vector

I'm getting the above error in stl_algo.h and can't pinpoint the problem as there are so many vectors involved.

```
    for (unsigned i=0;i < subsets.size(); i++) {
        do {
        permutations.push_back(subsets[i]);}
        while (next_permutation(begin(subsets[i]), end(subsets[i])));
    }


    for (unsigned i = 0; i < permutations.size(); i++) {
            if (find(wordlist.begin(), wordlist.end(), permutations[i]) != wordlist.end())
                first_words.push_back(permutations[i]);

    }

  ...

    for (const auto& str: subsets)
        set_difference(str.begin(), str.end(), letters.begin(), letters.end(), back_inserter(complement_sets));
```

Comment: On which line you gets this error?

Comment: `auto` defaults to taking stuff by _value_. So you're only sorting copies of the strings, etc. `auto&` is what you want, it will use references to the original objects.

Comment: It's coming outside of the main debugger and in stl_algo.h line 6000, between lines of build language like __glibcxx_function_requires(_OutputIteratorConcept<_OutputIterator etc., so I can't tell.

Comment: @aj1204 Everywhere where you want to access the elements by reference. `const auto&` if you're not intending to modify them.

Comment: @aj1204 the compiler typically prints the whole "stack" of the syntax analysis that caused the error. There should be some of *your* code somewhere therein.

Answer (score 1):

You need to learn how to read the output of the compiler, usually it tells you not only the line where the problem occurs, but also where the line originated, especially when using templates (or macros).

So e.g. MSVC gives me the following output:

```
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\algorithm(3710): error C2679: binary '=' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'char' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\iterator(59): could be 'std::back_insert_iterator<std::vector<std::string,std::allocator<_Ty>>> &std::back_insert_iterator<std::vector<_Ty,std::allocator<_Ty>>>::operator =(const std::back_insert_iterator<std::vector<_Ty,std::allocator<_Ty>>> &)'
          with
          [
              _Ty=std::string
          ]
          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\iterator(36): or       'std::back_insert_iterator<std::vector<std::string,std::allocator<_Ty>>> &std::back_insert_iterator<std::vector<_Ty,std::allocator<_Ty>>>::operator =(std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>> &&)'
          with
          [
              _Ty=std::string
          ]
          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\iterator(30): or       'std::back_insert_iterator<std::vector<std::string,std::allocator<_Ty>>> &std::back_insert_iterator<std::vector<_Ty,std::allocator<_Ty>>>::operator =(const std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>> &)'
          with
          [
              _Ty=std::string
          ]
          while trying to match the argument list '(std::back_insert_iterator<std::vector<std::string,std::allocator<_Ty>>>, char)'
          with
          [
              _Ty=std::string
          ]
          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\algorithm(3748) : see reference to function template instantiation '_OutIt std::_Set_difference<_InIt1,_InIt2,_OutIt,_Pr>(_InIt1,_InIt1,_InIt2,_InIt2,_OutIt,_Pr)' being compiled
          with
          [
              _OutIt=std::back_insert_iterator<std::vector<std::string,std::allocator<std::string>>>
  ,            _InIt1=char *
  ,            _InIt2=char *
  ,            _Pr=std::less<void>
          ]
          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\algorithm(3778) : see reference to function template instantiation '_OutIt std::_Set_difference2<char*,char*,_OutIt,_Pr>(_InIt1,_InIt1,_InIt2,_InIt2,_OutIt,_Pr,std::true_type)' being compiled
          with
          [
              _OutIt=std::back_insert_iterator<std::vector<std::string,std::allocator<std::string>>>
  ,            _Pr=std::less<void>
  ,            _InIt1=char *
  ,            _InIt2=char *
          ]
          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\algorithm(3808) : see reference to function template instantiation '_OutIt std::set_difference<_InIt1,_InIt2,_OutIt,std::less<void>>(_InIt1,_InIt1,_InIt2,_InIt2,_OutIt,_Pr)' being compiled
          with
          [
              _OutIt=std::back_insert_iterator<std::vector<std::string,std::allocator<std::string>>>
  ,            _InIt1=std::_String_iterator<std::_String_val<std::_Simple_types<char>>>
  ,            _InIt2=std::_String_iterator<std::_String_val<std::_Simple_types<char>>>
  ,            _Pr=std::less<void>
          ]
          c:\users\marvin\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\consoleapplication1\consoleapplication1\consoleapplication1.cpp(43) : see reference to function template instantiation '_OutIt std::set_difference<std::_String_iterator<std::_String_val<std::_Simple_types<char>>>,std::_String_iterator<std::_String_val<std::_Simple_types<char>>>,std::back_insert_iterator<std::vector<std::string,std::allocator<_Ty>>>>(_InIt1,_InIt1,_InIt2,_InIt2,_OutIt)' being compiled
          with
          [
              _OutIt=std::back_insert_iterator<std::vector<std::string,std::allocator<std::string>>>
  ,            _Ty=std::string
  ,            _InIt1=std::_String_iterator<std::_String_val<std::_Simple_types<char>>>
  ,            _InIt2=std::_String_iterator<std::_String_val<std::_Simple_types<char>>>
          ]
```

Important are the last lines:

```
          c:\users\marvin\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\consoleapplication1\consoleapplication1\consoleapplication1.cpp(43) : see reference to function template instantiation '_OutIt std::set_difference<std::_String_iterator<std::_String_val<std::_Simple_types<char>>>,std::_String_iterator<std::_String_val<std::_Simple_types<char>>>,std::back_insert_iterator<std::vector<std::string,std::allocator<_Ty>>>>(_InIt1,_InIt1,_InIt2,_InIt2,_OutIt)' being compiled
          with
          [
              _OutIt=std::back_insert_iterator<std::vector<std::string,std::allocator<std::string>>>
  ,            _Ty=std::string
  ,            _InIt1=std::_String_iterator<std::_String_val<std::_Simple_types<char>>>
  ,            _InIt2=std::_String_iterator<std::_String_val<std::_Simple_types<char>>>
          ]
```

Line 43 of my consoleapplication1.cpp:

```cpp
set_difference( str.begin(), str.end(), letters.begin(), letters.end(), back_inserter( complement_sets ) );
```

The problem here is you are comparing two sets of chars, but trying to insert it into a list of strings.
You need to pass a string into the back_inserter and not a vector of strings.